# pymysql operational error 1054: inserted values are read as columns

Tags: python-3.x, sql-insert, pymysql

I've been recently struggling with an error when I am trying to use the following code to insert a line of code into a table using pymysql:

```
sql = 'INSERT INTO `db`.`table`(`cola`,`colb`) VALUES (`%s`,%s);'
vals = ('This is a string',227.77)
cur.execute(sql,vals)
```

I also commit it, but I don't think that forgetting to commit is the issue here.
When I run my code, I end up getting the error:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column ''This is a string'' in 'field list'")
```

I am not sure if I did something wrong here, because when I use pymysql to look at the columns in db.table, both cola and colb are present. Also, I do not know why something in VALUES() is ending up being read as a column? The same thing happens when I try other methods of formatting the string.

Thank you so much for any insights you may have! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Remove the backticks around the first `%s`.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this! I get a syntax error when I do that, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I added double quotes around the `%s` and it worked okay for strings. Inserting a number works fine in the way I wrote above.